# Код на языке Python с if elif else не работает

Tags: python, if, variable

Код не работает:

File "D:\PythonCodes\ShidTycoon.py", line 4

```
if play == new or play == New
```

```
    if play == new or play == New
   print("new")
  elif play == load or play == Load
   print("load")
  else:
    print("Invalid Answer")
    start()
```

Comment: Приведите код в порядок - расставьте требуемые отступы.

Comment: читай текст ошибки, там все написано. И перечитай учебник на тему в чем разница между именем переменной и ее значением.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чисто по наитию поправил Ваш код:

```py
def start():
    play = input("New or Load(write on English): ")
    if play.lower() == 'new':
        print("new")
    elif play.lower() == 'load':
        print("load")
    else:
        print("Invalid Answer")


start()
```

> Править Ваш вопрос не стал, поскольку там не понятно, где вы ошиблись в коде а где в форматировании текста вопроса.